# A-Frame: Use different version/ specific commit of three.js

Tags: javascript, git, github, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to use a [specific commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14950) that was not merged onto the official Three.js repository because it may solve a specific problem I am having,
how do I use this specific commit in three.js for A-Frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will need to build it yourself. No guarantees if the three.js version plays well with A-Frame.

```
git clone git@github.com:aframevr/aframe
Change package.json to three.js version (e.g., "mrdoob/three.js#commithash")
npm install
npm run dist
```

Comment: would the package.json look like

`"three": "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git#fd5077bd2156ea52fa87620bc8aceb9022f24f59"`